# How to trim only the file name from a path which is having filename with extension using java script?

Tags: javascript, html, string

I am using `var documentName = $('#documentFile').val().split('\\').pop();`
my output is filename with extension.

The output which I wanted is only the file name without extension

Comment: documentName.split('.')[0] will give you the name without ext.

Comment: use this filename.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')....and this questions is duplicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly i believe that you have to escape your `backslash` so the correct way to extract your filename would be `var documentName = $('#documentFile').val().split('\\').pop()`. After this you can just chain a `.split()` to your code and it should work. you could try `var documentName = $('#documentFile').val().split('\\').pop().split(".")[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Once you have `documentName` as the filename without the path, you can get the filename without the extension like this:

```
let name = documentName;
const index = documentName.lastIndexOf(".");
if (index > 0) {
  name = documentName.substring(0,index);
}
// `name` now contains the name without the extension
```

Note that I'm using `lastIndexOf` to handle the case of multiple dots in a filename (like "file.name.txt"), and if there is no extension you just get the original name.

Comment: It does work..Thank you for the **lastIndexOf** logic

Comment: thanks - if you like the answer please mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) again.

```
var documentName = $('#documentFile').val().split('\\').pop();
documentName.split('.').pop();
documentName.join('.');
```

Note that I've used a double backslash because the first one tries to escape the single quote, using double backslash will stop this from happening.

Comment: var without Extention will give only the extension...My expected output is only the file name, not the extension

Answer (score 0):

You can use fileReader in js. In fileName you get only file name.

```
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
        const self = this;
        const file = event.target.files[0]
        let reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload = function (event) {
           self.setState({ fileName: event.target.result });
        }

        reader.readAsText(file);

    }
```